# Unable to use Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Whenever I deploy a Xamarin app on VS Android Emulator, the output window shows

> Validating emulator arguments...
>
> Determining if emulator is already running...
>
> Emulator is already running.

And it doesn't proceed further. Yes, the emulator is running, but the deployment process doesnt start.

And if the emulator isn't running, the output windows shows

> Emulator launched successfully.

And then again, does not proceed further.

Comment: In the Xamarin properties file, is "Use fast deployment" checked?

Comment: @JohnKemnetz, yes, it is checked. I unchecked it, and still nothing. :(

Comment: Can you check that you have adb.exe installed? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#ADB

Answer (score 0):

Is the package name starting with upper case? If so change it to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, then closed out of everything, re-launched VS as administrator and then the emulator launched as usual but the app deployed and launched as well. Hope this might work for you too.